# Download file weekly from FTP to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, ftp, hdfs, cloudera, oozie

I want to automate the weekly download of a file from an ftp server into a CDH5 hadoop cluster. What would be the best way to do this?

I was thinking about an Oozie coordinator job but I can't think of a good method to download the file.

Comment: Also a good idea, but what about downloading the file? I was thinking about using distcp, but maybe there is a more elegant solution?

Comment: distcp is elegant! I can't think of something more elegant :)

Comment: When I use this command:

hadoop distcp ftp://ftpserveraddress/ hdfs:/user/myuser/test/

I get a java.io.IOException: Login failed on server - serveraddress, port - 21 exception... I can do curl without problems. Should I use another port than 21? Or maybe hftp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using CDH5, it's worth noting that the [NFSv3](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-4750) interface to HDFS is included in  that Hadoop distribution.  You should check for "[Configuring an NFSv3 Gateway](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/CDH5-Installation-Guide/cdh5ig_NFSv3_gateway.html)" in the CDH5 Installation Guide documentation.

Once that's done, you could use wget, curl, python, etc. to put the file onto the NFS mount.  You probably want to do this through Oozie ... go into the job Designer and create a copy of the "Shell" command.  Put in the command that you've selected to do the data transfer (python script, curl, ftp, etc), and parameterize the job using ${myVar}.

It's not perfect, but I think it's fairly elegant.

Comment: In the meantime I have something similar going on. I use a shell script to mount the ftp server with curlftpfs and then pull the files into hdfs using copyFromLocal. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to pull a file.

One simple solution is that you can use coordinator which runs a workflow.

Workflow should have shell action

http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/DG_ShellActionExtension.html

The script in that can just have

wget http://myftp.com/file.name

You can do all what you want in script

Comment: I have a shell script now which mounts the ftp server into the filesystem using curlftpfs and then pull the files into hdfs using copyFromLocal. What would be the advantage using an Oozie coordinator and workflow over crontab?