# Best way to trigger execution at File arrival at NFS using OOZIE

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, oozie, nfs

Following [1](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/57661/hdfs-best-way-to-trigger-execution-at-file-arrival.html) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374057/download-file-weekly-from-ftp-to-hdfs/22387744#22387744):
Different types of files enter my NFS directory from time to time. I would like to use OOZIE or any other HDFS solution to trigger the file arrival event and to copy the file into specific location at the HDFS in accordance to its type. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Apache Flume…........??

Answer (score 1):

Best way is very subjective term. It largely depends on, what kind of data, frequency and what sorts of things should happen once the data arrive at specific location.

Apache flume can monitor specific folder for data availability and push it down to any sink like HDFS **as-is**. Flume is good for streaming data.But it does only one specific job- just moving data from place to place.

But on other hand, look up Oozie Coordinators. Coordinators have data availability trigger and with oozie you can perform all sort of ETL operations after data arrives using tools like spark,hive,pig etc and push it down to hdfs using shell actions. You can schedule jobs to run during specific times,frequency or have job send you an email if something goes wrong...

Comment: Thanks a lot @Pushkr! Can you direct me where can I find a source for code of Oozie Coordinators that  trigger the file arrival and copy the file into specific location at the HDFS?

Comment: google is your friend mate. But here is one which has some samples - https://github.com/yahoo/oozie/wiki/Oozie-Coord-Use-Cases

Comment: Dear  @Pushkr, does Oozie Coordinators support also file arrival at NFS and not only HDFS? please refer to this: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-Processing-and-Workflow/Getting-Oozie-Coordinator-datasets-working-with-S3-after-a-lost/td-p/27233

Comment: Good question. I am really not sure because oozie document only specifies that dataset URI it can accept is either hdfs or hcatlog. Lookup 'Dataset URI-Template types' under [this link](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a5._Dataset)

Comment: Thanks again, this was the target of my question at first. In case OOZIE doesn't support NFS, is there an alternative?